# How to place image over image without position absolute

Tags: css, position, css-position, absolute

I want to create a `HTML` Email template, some of the `css` style properties are not allowed by Email Providers like `Gmail`, `Outlook`, is one such property is `position:absolute`. I want to place image over image, using `div's` and `position:absolute` I'm able to do it as [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vhkssL0q/4/). How can we achieve [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vhkssL0q/) using `tables` without using `position:absolute`. I had searched over internet but have not found any related articles which gives solution.

Following are JSFiddle Links: With Div's: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vhkssL0q/4/),
With Tables: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vhkssL0q/).

Edit: At least is it possible or not I want to know ?

Comment: negative margins are also ignored by email providers.

Comment: Use your favorite image editor and merge those two.

Comment: I need to achieve dynamically, means images will be rendered dynamically programmatically. So, I can't do it.

Comment: if margin is not allowed... have you tried using negative left position?

Comment: I haven't tried, I'll try now.

Comment: Whatever you try... even if it works in one client, I'd kindly discourage you to do such overlapping stuff in primitive email clients.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vhkssL0q/8/ example using inline-block and negative positions. Try before buy :)

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan, I'll try your solution.

Comment: It's helpful to always keep an eye to https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

you could use negative margins and vertical-align:

```html
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
<img src="http://s17.postimg.org/ypnmpvdu7/cute_cartoons_21.jpg" style="" width="300px" height="300px" />
<img src="http://s17.postimg.org/bmx3qpccr/contest_badge_rank_1.png" style="margin-left:-150px;position:relative;vertical-align:60px; "/>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhkssL0q/10/